# "Convert" tk.ACTIVE to the index (line number) in a listbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, listbox

Let's get the formalities out of the way:  This is about Python 2.7.x running on Windows 7.

I'm creating a subclass of the Tkinter listbox widget, and one of the things I need the subclass to provide is a property containing the index (line number) of the line that is currently active (i.e. has the focus).  I know that Tkinter supports the constant `tk.ACTIVE` for all listbox methods that take an index, but in my custom widget this property needs to always be an *integer*, never a string.

I've scoured the documents but there doesn't seem to be method that will return the index of the active line, nor a way to "convert" `tk.ACTIVE` to its effective index number.  Methods like `curselection()` or `selection_includes()` are not helpful because this listbox is always going to have a `selectmode` of `tk.EXTENDED` -- which means any number of lines may be selected and further that the current active line may or may not be among them.

I considered using an event binding to wait for arrow keys, mouse clicks, etc. and look for changes to the `curselection()` tuple, but this is not quite helpful or straightforward either.  E.g. suppose the user shift-clicks to select a range -- he may go top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top, and either way the tuple will just show the range, not which line is active.

So then: is there any way at all (overt or sneaky, simple or complex) to get the equivalent index number for the `tk.ACTIVE` line?

Comment: What documentation did you "scour"?  The listbox has an `index` method specifically for getting a numerical index of an element. This method should be present in most tkinter documentation.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Oh geez. I've been using a PDF downloaded from New Mexico Tech Computer Center, authored by John Shipman... python.org links to this as a recommended source.  I also checked https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm.  Both sources give the same description of the `index` method:  "If possible, positions the visible part of the listbox so that the line containing index i is at the top
of the widget."  Not one word about it *returning* anything, only a statement that it repositions the current scrolling.

Comment: that's unfortunate. That description is completely wrong. The `index` method simply converts an index to its canonical form. The official documentation of the listbox method is this: "Returns the integer index value that corresponds to index. If index is end the return value is a count of the number of elements in the listbox (not the index of the last element)." I've sent a message to that website to let them know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to get the line number of the active line of the listbox is to use the `index` method: `listbox.index(tk.ACTIVE)`.

Comment: Thanks much.  See my comment above to Bryan Oakley for why I missed this obvious answer.